# Random variables and their values

Tags: random-variable

I have two questions:

**1. Which one is determined first: (i) Random variable's values, (ii) the random experiment?**

For instance [this](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/ranvar.htm) link says the following:

> Suppose a variable X can take the values 1, 2, 3, or 4.
>
> The probabilities associated with each outcome are described by the following table:

```
Outcome     1   2   3   4
Probability 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.2
```

> The probability that X is equal to 2 or 3 is the sum of the two probabilities: P(X = 2 or X = 3) = P(X = 2) + P(X = 3) = 0.3 + 0.4 = 0.7. Similarly, the probability that X is greater than 1 is equal to 1 - P(X = 1) = 1 - 0.1 = 0.9, by the complement rule.

Which means, the values of Random Variables are decided first which is very unusual.

**2. Can a Random Variable take random values?**

For instance, can we roll a die and a random variable associated with it take on,

X = {99, 0, 100, 1, -35, 2.4} ?

Comment: The random experiment defines the random variable if you associate the values of the outcomes and probabilities with the random variable You can define a random variable as you did for X in part 2 by say associating the die outcome 1 with 99, 2 with 0, 3 with 100, 4 with 1, 5 with .-35 and 6 with 2.4. Presumably you would assign 1/6 as the probability for each of the 6 possible outcomes.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean "the values of Random Variables are decided first which is very unusual". The Random variable is a measurable function, i.e probabilities of events involving the function can be computed, it is a function on the events (certain sets) .